# ¿Saben como añadir un pedazo de codigo en el archivo de construccion del proyecto en JAVA?

Tags: java, gradle

queiro descargar un pdf con un par de detalles y lo que quiero añadir al archivo contruccion para ello busque en google y me salio el siguiente codigo que tengo que añadir al Build y otro en la clase Main, esto es solo lo del Build:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

application {
    mainClass = 'io.github.picodotdev.blogbitix.javapdf.Main'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
} 

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.16'
}
```

Comment: Ese código se agrega a un proyecto que utiliza Gradle para hacer su build en el archivo build.gradle, si tu proyecto ocupa Maven puedes ir a mvnrepository y buscar por ejemplo https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/2.0.28 y agregar el código que te entregan en esa página en el archivo pom.xml